# Can't find unclosed element in XML

Tags: xml

I have a large XML file (~18MB). Apparently there is a tag somewhere in it that isn't closed. I know this because when I ran the W3C markup validation tool (validator.w3.org), I get the following error:

`You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".`

My question is how I might go about finding this missing closed element among the 500,000 lines in the file. Is there a tool I could use that would suggest places where there might be a problem -- such as an element that has not been closed after a certain number of lines?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have an XML Schema for the file?

Comment: Afraid not. Would make things a lot easier if people followed good practice, wouldn't it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which has an excellent XML Tools plugin that lets you check XML Syntax and takes you to the line that is problematic. It also has useful utilities.

[image]

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but does the file require a schema for this to work?

Comment: Nope. No schema required. Although if you do have one, you can validate your XML against the schema with another item from the menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just telling me there's a premature end at the final line of the file. This is similar to what the w3 validator was doing I guess.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the closing tag for one of the outer elements.Is it possible to share the xml file?

Comment: You're right: there was an erroneous closing tag for the outer element buried in the file somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @itzy how can you find the incorrect closing tag at the end?

Answer (score 5):

I just opened an XML file in VS 2010 (with ReSharper), broke the XML and what do you know? The error was highlighted immediately. If you have access to the same, it's that simple.

Comment: Perfect! Notepad++ gave me useless information, VS gave me exactly the right information. Didn't know VS had that tool. :)

Comment: This was the best solution I found. The other solutions posted required a lot of manually digging. Installing Visual Studio, then installing the ReSharper plugin took me line by line to each error, and suggested a fix for them. I used this to repair a corrupted Word document in about 30 seconds, after trying in Notepad++ for about 2 hours.

Answer (score 5):

[`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) is a standard tool for this. From the [Validation & DTDs](http://xmlsoft.org/xmldtd.html#validate) page:

> The simplest way is to use the xmllint program included with libxml. The --valid option turns-on validation of the files given as input. For example the following validates a copy of the first revision of the XML 1.0 specification:

```
xmllint --valid --noout test/valid/REC-xml-19980210.xml
```

> the -- noout is used to disable output of the resulting tree.
>
> The --dtdvalid dtd allows validation of the document(s) against a given DTD.
>
> Libxml2 exports an API to handle DTDs and validation, check the associated description.

If your document isn't "pretty-printed" it can still be hard to find the offending node, so you might want to use xmllint to rewrite the file to be indented.

Comment: This isn't a validation problem.  The document's not invalid, it's poorly-formed.  I haven't used `xmllint`, so I don't know whether or not it's good for finding unclosed tags, but validating against a schema or DTD not only won't help, it isn't possible.

Comment: I don't understand. The OP said the XML is failing the validation test, yet you say it isn't a validation problem. In XML, [all tags have to be closed](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp). A tag that isn't closed, either with an end tag or by being self-closing, will cause a validation error.

Comment: The validation tool's failing to validate the document.  But that's not because the document's invalid.  It's because it's not well-formed XML.  It's not relevant to talk about whether a string of characters is valid XML if it's not well-formed XML - strictly speaking, if it's not well-formed XML, it's not an XML document at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have an XML Schema, there is no fool-proof way of finding the offending code, for example XML allows for recursive structures. But you CAN write your own XML Schema, although that will potentially be a lot of stuff to learn. Alternatively, I would create a simple, stupid, validator of the node level and the element name, as so:

```cs
private void parseAndCheckStructure(XMLStreamReader reader) throws XMLStreamException {

    // first read header, this is probably not the offending element (?)
    int event = -1;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        event = reader.next();
        if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
            break;
        } else if (event == XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT) {
            throw new XMLStreamException();
        }
    }

    // read the rest of the document.
    int level = 1;
    do {
        event = reader.next();
        if (event == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
            level++;
            String localName = reader.getLocalName();
            if(localName.equals("FirstElement")) {
                parseFirstElementWithALoopLikeTheCurrent(reader);

                level--;
            } else if(localName.equals("SecondElement")) {
                parseSecondElementWithALoopLikeTheCurrent(reader);

                level--;

            } else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown element " + localName + " at level " + level + " and location " + reader.getLocation());

        } else if(event == XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
            // keep track of level
            level--;
        }
    } while(level > 0);

}
```

Alternatively, parse the whole document within the above do-while loop, and do checks like

```cs
if(level == 4 && localName.equals("MyElement")) {
    // ok
} else {
    // throw exception with the location
}
```

It sucks, but it works.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with another suggestion, but this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try Opening the .xml file with chrome browser, It'll pin point the exact location of the fault.