# Detect All Unclosed Tags in R XML

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, xml2

I am attempting to parse an XML file that I download from a sharepoint site (.aspx page). When using `XML::xmlParse`, or `xml2::read_xml`, I receive the following error:

> `Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values [38]`

I've scoured the internet searching for a solution, but nothing I've found works. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463154/unescaped-not-allowed-in-attributes-values-error-in-r) led me to trying to go line-by-line and replace unclosed tags with their respective `"&lt"` and `"&gt"` values, but I haven't been able to find a clean solution to even detect unclosed tags. [This semi-outdated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533355/cant-find-unclosed-element-in-xml) suggests using additional tools for this detection, which is not ideal for my use case as I am needing this to be integrated into a larger process that runs daily.

So, I guess what I'm looking for is an answer to one of the following:

1. Is there a parsing option in any XML parser package in R that handles unescaped '<' signs?
2. Is there an easy way to detect all unclosed tags from an XML file within R?
3. Is there any other solution that will allow me to parse an XML file with unescaped tags?

Any help would be **AWESOME**.

Examples of my output:

```
> xml2::read_xml(myfile)
Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values [38]

> XML::xmlParse(myfile)
Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
attributes construct error
Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 4
Extra content at the end of the document
Error: 1: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
2: attributes construct error
3: Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 4
4: Extra content at the end of the document
```

Comment: First realize that your data is not XML if it contains unescaped `<` characters that are not proper parts of the markup.  Languages have rules, and your textual data violates the rules for being XML.  Therefore, tools meant to be used with XML are in general not going to be able to help you.  See the duplicate link for ways to cleanup your textual data to be well-formed XML before attempting to parse it in R as XML; the accepted answer also mentions `htmlTreeParse()`, which might be able to parse the problematic markup directly in R (but it'd be better if you cleaned up the data first).